# Apps crashing on my Desktop

Tags: boot, slack

Any time I open VS Code or Slack on my Ubuntu Desktop I get kicked to the login screen. When I log in it is as if I rebooted, nothing is open. They work on my laptop installation however I cant get to the log in screen at all on the laptop without first going to advanced options and back to normal boot.
Any suggestions for either issue would be great.

Comment: can you run them from the command line and post the error output to your question... you can dump the output to a file like this `$ mycommand >> ~/error.log`

Comment: I did that. Ran from terminal. Ubuntu closed out to log in screen. Error log is blank.

Comment: Uninstalled slack and installed with terminal. Tried to run from terminal and got this.

ssh: Could not resolve hostname slack-master: Name or service not known
rsync: did not see server greeting
rsync error: error starting client-server protocol (code 5) at main.c(1666) [Receiver=3.1.2]
FATAL[slack-getroles]: 'rsync --links --times -e ssh slack-master::slack/etc/roles.conf /var/cache/slack/_role_list' exited 5 at /usr/lib/slack/slack-getroles line 158.
FATAL[slack]: '/usr/lib/slack/slack-getroles' exited 5 at /usr/sbin/slack line 205.

Comment: could you edit your question and add the output of that command there so it is more readable? thanks|!

Comment: ssh: Could not resolve hostname slack-master: Name or service not known 
    rsync: did not see server greeting rsync error: error starting client-server 
    protocol (code 5) at main.c(1666) [Receiver=3.1.2] FATAL[slack-getroles]: 
    'rsync --links --times -e ssh slack-master::slack/etc/roles.conf 
    /var/cache/slack/_role_list' exited 5 at /usr/lib/slack/slack-getroles line 158. 
    FATAL[slack]: '/usr/lib/slack/slack-getroles' exited 5 at /usr/sbin/slack line 
    205.

Comment: In the future, it is preferable to edit your question and add relevant info there, wrapped in {} blocks... anyway, i have done this for you so you can see what I mean :)